# Turning the "line number" on in kile?

Tags: line-numbering, kile

I think it is a really easy problem, but Google could not help and this searching function neither. I love kile, but the settings section is like a big mess for me. I would love to turn on a bar on the side of the document, which shows me the line numbering? Not in the finished PDF but in the "working area" of kile.

I hope you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Since Kile uses Kate, maybe https://superuser.com/questions/918189/how-to-make-kate-remember-to-always-show-line-numbers is relevant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Kile 2.1.3 at least: View --> Line numbers. Shortcut key is <kbd>F11</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: There is no such menu item in my Kile, but F11 worked :)

Comment: Kile 2.9.92 in 20201014. 1) Einstellungen / Kile einrichten 2) Editor / Erscheinungsbild / Randbereiche 4) Zeilennummern anzeigen. BUT F11 works too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Kile 2.9.91, and it is something you could only do in "Configure Kile". Setting it in Menu Bar doesn't become permanent. In other words, Marjin's comment worked for me.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Kile 2.9.93` which by default doesn't show line numbers.
Though I was able to use the shortcut <kbd>F11</kbd>, I have to press this key every time I opened `Kile`.

#### To permanently show line numbers:

1. Go to `Setting` => `Configure Kile`
2. On the left side of the menu opened, go to `Editor` => `Appreance`
3. Open `Borders` tab
4. Check the **☑** `Show line numbers` option
5. Click `OK`

*P.S. Thanks [@Margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn) for [this link](https://superuser.com/a/918228/990484).*

Namaste